# Как лучше организовать код/скрипт?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Есть такая страница у сайта, как лучше организовывать скрипт в таком случаи. Допустим человек заполнил и нажал "Разместить", объявление добавилось в блок ниже, допустим я это реализовал, а дальше какая должна быть логика для реализации редактирования сообщения и есть ли какие-нибудь подводные камни при таком подходе? Как это сделать правильно, чтобы back-end разработчик без проблем смог это прикрутить? (Пишу на нативном JavaScript все скрипты).

Comment: А в чем конкретно проблема?